# Postfix null client for multiple domains - how?

Tags: postfix, null-client

I've configured PostFix as a null client on my machine as it's said [here](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#null_client).

But some mail got bounced. I checked log and found there, that "from" values equal script username on the machine, not email address in the email:

```
Apr 25 13:12:22 server2 postfix/qmgr[1598]: C3937504B8049: from=<vipsup@gsmforum.ru>, size=2041, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 25 13:12:23 server2 postfix/qmgr[1598]: 0F175504B804A: from=<>, size=3956, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 25 13:12:50 server2 postfix/pickup[1597]: 23967151C8001: uid=528 from=<gsmbaza>
Apr 25 13:12:50 server2 postfix/qmgr[1598]: 23967151C8001: from=<gsmbaza@gsmforum.ru>, size=5223, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 25 13:12:50 server2 postfix/qmgr[1598]: A4970504B8049: from=<>, size=7046, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 25 13:13:43 server2 postfix/pickup[1597]: A8DC5504B8049: uid=501 from=<vipsup>
Apr 25 13:13:43 server2 postfix/qmgr[1598]: A8DC5504B8049: from=<vipsup@gsmforum.ru>, size=2029, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 25 13:13:44 server2 postfix/qmgr[1598]: EEBDE504B804A: from=<>, size=3926, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 25 13:14:20 server2 postfix/pickup[1597]: 0743B504B8049: uid=501 from=<vipsup>
Apr 25 13:14:20 server2 postfix/qmgr[1598]: 0743B504B8049: from=<vipsup@gsmforum.ru>, size=2036, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 25 13:14:21 server2 postfix/pickup[1597]: 194FC504B804D: uid=528 from=<gsmbaza>
Apr 25 13:14:21 server2 postfix/qmgr[1598]: E5E17504B804A: from=<>, size=3937, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 25 13:14:22 server2 postfix/qmgr[1598]: 194FC504B804D: from=<gsmbaza@gsmforum.ru>, size=6419808, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 25 13:14:22 server2 postfix/qmgr[1598]: 9F595504B8045: from=<>, size=2542, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 25 13:15:12 server2 postfix/pickup[1597]: D9879504B8045: uid=528 from=<gsmbaza>
Apr 25 13:15:12 server2 postfix/qmgr[1598]: D9879504B8045: from=<gsmbaza@gsmforum.ru>, size=722, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 25 13:15:13 server2 postfix/qmgr[1598]: 29CA1504B8049: from=<>, size=2620, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

Emails got bounced like this:

```
Apr 25 13:17:24 server2 postfix/pickup[4137]: 2F33F504B8045: uid=501 from=<vipsup>
Apr 25 13:17:24 server2 postfix/cleanup[4229]: 2F33F504B8045: message-id=<20110425091723.8d2335c96ee9@www.vipgsmsupport.com>
Apr 25 13:17:24 server2 postfix/qmgr[1598]: 2F33F504B8045: from=<vipsup@gsmforum.ru>, size=2033, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 25 13:17:24 server2 postfix/smtp[4231]: 2F33F504B8045: to=<reandoynthea@hotmail.com>, relay=mx.yandex.ru[93.158.134.89]:25, delay=0.47, delays=0.27/0/0.12/0.08, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host mx.yandex.ru[93.158.134.89] said: 550 5.7.1 No such user! (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

How do I setup postfix correctly?

Email is sent by php scripts using "sendmail" binary (postfix replacement of it).

PostFix configuration:

```
[root@server2 log]# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debug_peer_list = 127.0.0.1
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
local_transport = error:local delivery is disabled
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Comment: Please show output of `postconf -n`.

Answer (score 1):

To set From: e-mail address you need to use `-f` option for `sendmail` binary.

Second bounce probably caused by `relay_host` pointing to server (mx.yandex.ru) which doesn't relay mail for your server.

Comment: Sometimes I cannot use `-f` everywhere. And does it really affect STMP `MAIL FROM` command? `relayhost` is commented in config file.